# REST API payment.create not creating payment

Tags: paypal

I have a backend webservice (not a web page) that is attempting to create a payment from a front end client. After a couple of goes where I did not quite have the data matching between details and transaction list, where I got suitable error messages from the sandpit explaining what was wrong, I eventually got the payment.create method to execute without throwing an exception. Unfortunately, while I can see the existence of SSL traffic between the test web service and the paypal, when the routine returns I have no links and no status of created. I may have completely misunderstood the mechanics of the api, but in the absence of any error or exception from the call, I am a little stumped.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
    var clientid = config[BaseConstants.ClientId];
    var clientSecret = config[BaseConstants.ClientSecret];
    var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientid, clientSecret, config).GetAccessToken();
    var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
    var itemList = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() };
    using (var context = new PETTEntities3())
    {
      SubscriptionType subType = context.SubscriptionTypes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubscriptionTypeID == Subscription.SubscriptionTypeID);
      itemList.items.Add(new Item()
      {
        name = subType.SubscriptionName,
        currency = "NZD",
        price = (Subscription.Amount / (decimal)1.15).ToString("0.00"),
        quantity = "1",
        sku = subType.SubscriptionTypeID.ToString()
       });
       var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };
       var redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls()
       {
         cancel_url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaymentConfirmationURL"] + Subscription.PaymentApprovalID,
           return_url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaymentCancellationURL"] + Subscription.PaymentApprovalID
       };
       var details = new Details()
       {
         tax = (Subscription.Amount - decimal.Parse((Subscription.Amount / (decimal)1.15).ToString("0.00"))).ToString("0.00"),
         subtotal = (Subscription.Amount / (decimal)1.15).ToString("0.00"),
         shipping="0"
        };
        var amount = new Amount()
        {
          currency = "NZD",
          total = Subscription.Amount.ToString("0.00"),
          details = details              
        };
        var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
        transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
        {
          description = "PETT Subscription.",
          invoice_number = "PETT1420" + Subscription.SubscriptionID.ToString(),
          amount = amount,
          item_list = itemList
        });
        Payment payment = new Payment()
        {
          intent = "sale",
          payer = payer,
          transactions = transactionList,
          redirect_urls = redirectUrls
        };
        payment.Create(apiContext);
.... At this point the payment state is still null and no links are present even though I appear to have a successful call with no exceptions.
```

Any clues or insight as to what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, blindingly obvious. Wasn't paying attention to the function signature payment.create, it returns a new payment. Its that which you need to use, not the payment used to invoke create eg:

Payment paymentToUse = payment.Create(apiContext);

paymentToUse has all the goods im after.